# Meaning and usage of "off to the races"

Tags: idioms, vocabulary

What does "**off to the races**" mean and how to use this idiom?

Can you give me more examples to use this phrase?

I only found this definition, and it didn't click with me:

> (idiomatic) In or into a process of energetic engagement in some activity; in or into a phase of conspicuously increasing satisfaction or success.

Answer (score 2):

The following definition from the [McGraw-Hill Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/off+to+the+races) may help:

off to the races:

> Fig. an expression characterizing the activity or excitement that is just beginning; [we are] leaving for something interesting or exciting.
>
> *The tour bus is out in front waiting and we've said goodbye to everyone. Looks like we're off to the races.*

Comment: Let’s say I’m sitting in a roller coaster chair and I know there is no way to come back. Can I say something like this:

“We’re off to the races. There is no turning back.”

Comment: @Codewife_101 I think that would be an odd usage of that idiom, but it is hard to explain why.

Comment: Here's another dictionary link if you like it and want to add it to your answer: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/off+to+the+races